# Double forward slash skipped by a regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I need help with a regex in Ruby which fails, I did not figured out why.
I am using Ruby to grab portions of text from a large bio-database, which has the following
structure (I will show just two items for simplicity):

```
//
ID   IPI00303292.1         IPI;      PRT;   538 AA.
AC   IPI00303292;
DR   Superfamily; SSF48371; ARM; 1.
DR   UniProt/Swiss-Prot; P52294; IMA1_HUMAN; M.
DR   CleanEx; HS_KPNA1; -; -.
//
ID   IPI00301082.1         IPI;      PRT;   309 AA.
AC   IPI00301082;
DT   06-JUN-2003 (IPI Human rel. 2.20, Created)
//
```

i.e. database entries start with a line containing the IPI code and end with a double forward slash. I want to retrieve the information associated with specific IPI codes.
Let's say I want to get only the the text lines of `IPI00303292.1` spanning from the IPI code to the following `//`.

A Rubular test of `/(IPI00303292\.1).*\/\//m` regex grabs the whole displayed text (i.e. two entries) recognizing the last `//` while skipping the second between the two.

***Update:***
Hi, based on your valuable suggestions,I think I am close in getting a usable program for my purposes. The code is:

```
matches = []
no_matches = []

ipi = File.open('mini_alphaIPI.txt').collect do | var | # read the file containing IPI search codes
    var = var.chomp 

db = File.open('mini_human.dat') # read the file containing IPI data

db.readlines.map(&:chomp).slice_before(%r(\A//)).each do |db_record|
  db_record.shift
  next if db_record.empty?

matches.push(db_record) if db_record.first.include?(var)

if db_record.first.include?(var)  then
    matches.push(db_record)
    else
    no_matches.push(var)
end
end
end

File.open('out_raw.txt', "wb") do |file|
     matches.each do |z|
      file.puts z
  end
end
```

The last prblem to solve now is that I am getting two copies in the output file of the properly selected positive hits. I cannot get rid of such mistake. Please help .

Comment: Could you paste the link to that rubular test?

Comment: Would it not be easier to split by "//" first, and then select by the first chars of each item in the resultant array? e.g. `db_entries.split("//").select{|item| item.start_with? "ID   IPI00303292.1" }`

Comment: Make that `db_entries.split("//\n").select{|item| item.start_with? "ID   IPI00303292.1" }`

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical problem caused by using the greedy quantifier `*`. Use the non-greedy quantifier `*?` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby comes equipped with [`slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) which is a nice tool for this sort of problem:

```
require 'pp'

DATA.readlines.slice_before(%r(\A//)).each do |db_record|
  pp db_record
end

__END__
//
ID   IPI00303292.1         IPI;      PRT;   538 AA.
AC   IPI00303292;
DR   Superfamily; SSF48371; ARM; 1.
DR   UniProt/Swiss-Prot; P52294; IMA1_HUMAN; M.
DR   CleanEx; HS_KPNA1; -; -.
//
ID   IPI00301082.1         IPI;      PRT;   309 AA.
AC   IPI00301082;
DT   06-JUN-2003 (IPI Human rel. 2.20, Created)
//
```

Running the code outputs:

```
["//\n",
 "ID   IPI00303292.1         IPI;      PRT;   538 AA.\n",
 "AC   IPI00303292;\n",
 "DR   Superfamily; SSF48371; ARM; 1.\n",
 "DR   UniProt/Swiss-Prot; P52294; IMA1_HUMAN; M.\n",
 "DR   CleanEx; HS_KPNA1; -; -.\n"]
["//\n",
 "ID   IPI00301082.1         IPI;      PRT;   309 AA.\n",
 "AC   IPI00301082;\n",
 "DT   06-JUN-2003 (IPI Human rel. 2.20, Created)\n"]
["//\n"]
```

It scans an array, breaking it on the occurrence of lines that match a pattern, which, in this case, is `%r(\A//)`, or, in English, "lines that start with two forward slashes." The resulting array of arrays will be each group of records delimited by `//`.

Note that the lines have trailing new-lines. That can be fixed using:

```
DATA.readlines.map(&:chomp).slice_before(%r(\A//)).each do |db_record|
```

If you want to skip the first sub-array `//` entry use:

```
pp db_record[1..-1]
```

or:

```
db_record.shift
pp db_record
```

After cleanup, the code looks like:

```
require 'pp'

DATA.readlines.map(&:chomp).slice_before(%r(\A//)).each do |db_record|
    db_record.shift
    pp db_record
end
```

And running it looks like:

```
["ID   IPI00303292.1         IPI;      PRT;   538 AA.",
 "AC   IPI00303292;",
 "DR   Superfamily; SSF48371; ARM; 1.",
 "DR   UniProt/Swiss-Prot; P52294; IMA1_HUMAN; M.",
 "DR   CleanEx; HS_KPNA1; -; -."]
["ID   IPI00301082.1         IPI;      PRT;   309 AA.",
 "AC   IPI00301082;",
 "DT   06-JUN-2003 (IPI Human rel. 2.20, Created)"]
[]
```

Two tweaks and you're done:

```
DATA.readlines.map(&:chomp).slice_before(%r(\A//)).each do |db_record|
  db_record.shift
  next if db_record.empty?

  pp db_record if db_record.first['IPI00303292.1']

end
```

Which outputs:

```
["ID   IPI00303292.1         IPI;      PRT;   538 AA.",
 "AC   IPI00303292;",
 "DR   Superfamily; SSF48371; ARM; 1.",
 "DR   UniProt/Swiss-Prot; P52294; IMA1_HUMAN; M.",
 "DR   CleanEx; HS_KPNA1; -; -."]
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful reply. Since the IPI codes will be several (read from a file each one on a single line and put in a variable) with your approach I will end up with an array of arrays that I do not how to manage or dump it out as a text file. This is why I was trying to slurp the overall block of text at once. I will try to figure out how to deal with tables but, in the meantime,I would greatly appreciate if you could suggest how to dump out the table in a text file formatted as the input

Comment: Dealing with an array of arrays is an essential piece of knowledge in all programming languages, because they are an intermediate data construct. You will encounter them multiple times daily. It's also an essential trait for a programmer to dig in and discover how to do something, so search and read, and, if in a week's time you haven't figured it out, ping me with a comment, and I'll expand the answer.

Comment: Hi, I think I am almost to the point to get a usable program. Here it is:

Comment: Hi, `code`
ipi = File.open('mini_alphaIPI.txt').collect do | var | # IPIs
 var = var.chomp 
db = File.open('mini_human.dat') # data
db.readlines.map(&:chomp).slice_before(%r(\A//)).each do |db_record|
  db_record.shift
  next if db_record.empty?
matches.push(db_record) if db_record.first.include?(var)
if db_record.first.include?(var)  then
 matches.push(db_record)
 else
 no_matches.push(var)
end
end
end
File.open('out_raw.txt', "wb") do |file|
  matches.each do |z|
   file.puts z
  end
end `code` The problem now is that I am getting two copies of positive hits in the output file. Please help

Comment: Hi,
 printf("%d\n", 42);  /*ipi = File.open('mini_alphaIPI.txt').collect do |var| # IPIs
 var = var.chomp 
db = File.open('mini_human.dat') # data
db.readlines.map(&:chomp).slice_before(%r(\A//)).each do |db_record|
  db_record.shift
  next if db_record.empty?
matches.push(db_record) if db_record.first.include?(var)
if db_record.first.include?(var)  then
 matches.push(db_record)
 else
 no_matches.push(var)
end
end
end
File.open('out_raw.txt', "wb") do |file|
  matches.each do |z|
   file.puts z
  end
end */The problem is I am getting two copies of positive hits in the output file. Please help

Comment: Please don't use a comment to show code, because it is unreadable when finished. Instead, append it to your original question, using a line starting with `---` as a divider, so we can see its a new section. Also, don't post the same comment twice. You can edit them for up to five minutes, or copy your old one, then create a new one, then delete the old so you end up with just the one.

Answer (score 0):

- List item

The regex approach is a very difficult in this case, and I think the problem relies in `.` also matching `/`.

Almost achieved it with this regex:

```
%r{
  //\n                  # Match '//' and new line
  (?<item>              # Capture the item...
    [\n\w\s.,;\-\(\)]+  # And here comes the !"#%&@ł
  )                     # You need this to match a single appearance of '/' 
}x                      # e.g., not '//', and partial regex negation is a bit tricky...
```

However, it would much more easier to just use `split('//')` and continue the process from there.

```
DATA.split('//').each do |item|
  item.each_line do |line|
    # etc
  end
end
```

HOWDY: this works http://rubular.com/r/kH12xUyxR9

```
%r{
  (//)?\n
  (?<item>.+?)
  \n//
}xm
```

But this is just for curiosity, seriously, just use `split('//')`.